# sein and verb at end (spezialisiert)

Tags: grammar-identification

I was reading the sentence

> Diese Fachhochschule ist auf Medien und Design spezialisiert.

and I was wondering why the conjugated verb of spezialisieren is at the end of the sentence.

Using my current knowledge of German so far, I know that this is similar to the perfekt tense ("spoken past").

But, I was wondering - what kind of structure is being following in the sentence above?

Comment: I lack grammar knowledge so this is my opinion: you focus the sentence on the middle part: `ist spezialisiert auf` would emphasize theat there is a specialization (or there is a long list of words following so the verb would be lost at the end). Because the last part of a sentence might rather be lost when I read it - well in cases like this which is a neutral description and quite clear what the verb is.

Answer (score 2):

**Spezialisiert** isn't a conjugated verb in that sentence. It's the **Partizip II** of *spezialisieren*, which happens to be identical to the 3rd person singular and the 2nd person plural form. This is true for all *-ieren* verbs, and for most verbs with inseparable prefixes, too.

Most verbs build their *Perfekt* with the *haben* auxiliary:

> Die Fachschule hat den Schüler zum Fachmann spezialisiert.
>
> Der Fachmann hat sich spezialisiert.

For those "normal" verbs, the *Partizip II* is the result of an action. As participles may be used like adjectives, you can write:

> Ein Fachmann ist spezialisiert.
>
> Ein Fachmann bleibt spezialisiert.
>
> Ein Fachmann wird spezialisiert.

If you put it bland, these are predicative expressions as *Das Gras ist/bleibt/wird grün.*

German prefers to see them as different voices. The latter one is clearly passive voice, as it uses the *werden* auxiliary. It's called **Vorgangspassiv**. The first one with the *sein* auxiliary is seen as another passive voice: **Zustandspassiv**. The middle one with *bleiben* has no special name but you may see it as a special case of the *Zustandspassiv* voice.

Comment: It would also be possible to change the word order to "Diese Fachhochschule ist spezialisiert auf Medien und Design." This would slightly shift the emphasis of the sentence from the fact that the school did specialize at some topics at all to the topics themselves.

Answer (score 1):

As Janka said, 'spezialisiert' in the given sentence works like an adjective. Adjectives as well as verbs and nouns can be completed by prepositional phrases. Linguists call it the adjective's 'valency':

- **in** etwas gut sein (ich bin nicht so gut in Mathe)

The same structure with past participle adjectives:

1. **an** etwas interessiert sein, sich an etwas interessiert zeigen
2. **für** jemanden bestimmt sein (der Brief ist nicht für mich bestimmt)
3. **auf** etwas eingestellt / vorbereitet sein (ich war auf so viel Besuch nicht eingestellt / vorbereitet)
4. **über** etwas verwundert sein
5. **in** etwas bewandert / beschlagen sein
6. **mit** jemandem befreundet sein

and many many others.

In many cases it may be difficult to make the difference between a past participle as part of the predicate (in present perfect or in statal passive sentences / Zustandspassive) and as a mere adjective.

- mit etwas (immer) gut gefahren sein: *Mit den Maschinen von Bosch sind wir immer gut gefahren*.

This is a present perfect sentence, since you can transform the structure of the predicate into present tense:

- Nimm Bosch, damit fährst immer du gut.

This is not possible in the same way for 'interessiert sein an':

- *Ich interessiere (mich) an Kunst.

[A correct transformation would be: *Ich interessiere mich für Kunst*.]

- 120 Euro sind für die Vase geboten.
- Der Brief ist mit der Hand geschrieben.

These are 'Zustandspassive': *Jemand hat 120 Euro geboten. Jemand hat den Brief mit der Hand geschrieben*.

As you see, among the above examples the sentences 2., 3. and 4. may be interpreted *à la limite* as 'Zustandspassive: Jemand hat den Brief für mich bestimmt, ich habe mich auf so viele Leute nicht vorbereitet / eingestellt, ich habe mich darüber sehr verwundert (obsolete, in nowadays German 'gewundert').